# What is the difference between "Wherein" and "Whereas"?

Tags: difference

The meaning of the two words seems very much opposite to each other. I am confused how and where to use them.

Comment: Welcome to ELL :-). The questions that are answerable with a dictionary are [off topic](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site (and usually get closed), but if you edit your question to include the definitions you found, and point out the source of your confusion in those definitions the question would be on topic. Here's a [meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english) which might help you to do that :-).

Answer (score 2):

Wherein is used the same as *in which*, while whereas is used like *while*.

From the Oxford Dictionaries:

> [wherein](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wherein), adv.
>
> 1 [relative adverb] In which:
>
> 'the situation wherein the information will eventually be used'

---

> [whereas](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/whereas), conjunction
>
> 1 In contrast or comparison with the fact that:
>
> 'you treat the matter lightly, whereas I myself was never more serious'

---

> [while](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/while), conjunction
>
> 2 Whereas (indicating a contrast):
>
> 'one person wants out, while the other wants the relationship to continue'